# Text view wont align to center in android whenever I specify a text size

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem aligning my `TextView` to center even when using `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` whenever I specify a textSize.

If I use `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"` everything works fine but if I change that to **textSize="32sp"** then it wont align center

Below is my xml. My issue is ,what the `android:id="@+id/textViewTicket0"`?
It works fine and aligns to center if I don't specify a textSize using **dp** or **sp**.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:elevation=".5dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ricepaper">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textsIZE="32sp"
        android:text="CHOOSE PAYMENT METHOD"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTicket0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"/>

    <View android:background="#000" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="2px"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="SAN AGUSTIN MUSEUM"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTicket1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/mastercard"
        android:paddingTop=".5dp"
        android:paddingBottom=".5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />


    <View android:background="#000" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="2px"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="BAHAY TSINOY"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTicket2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/visa"
        android:paddingTop=".5dp"
        android:paddingBottom=".5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />


    <View android:background="#000" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="2px"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="BAHAY TSINOY"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTicket3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/paypal"
        android:paddingTop=".5dp"
        android:paddingBottom=".5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: screenshots please

Comment: Wrap it in a `RelativeLayout` and set `centerInParent` to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set gravity as:

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Comment: It works but what bugs me is why does it work without the android:gravity="center_horizontal" if I dont specify a font size and just use the android:attr/textAppearanceLarge ?  If I use textSize then its the only time center_horizontal is needed

Answer (score 0):

To align text inside TextView try this:

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the TextView,the property's name it's wrong.

```
enter code here<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    <!--This word is wrong.-->
    android:textsIZE="32sp"
    android:text="CHOOSE PAYMENT METHOD"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textViewTicket0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using gravity will solve your problem

```
    android:gravity="center"
```

Or You can also use

```
    android:textAlignment="center"
```

And also correct the capitalisation

```
    android:textSize="32sp"
```